# Adding additional properties without having to overwrite base properties

Tags: c#

I have a number of classes deriving from an abstract base class. The concrete classes are stored in a container by references to base class. The concrete classes have many properties which are used to bind to pages in a FixedDocument.

I want to add aditional properties to the concrete classes at runtime which will also bind to the FixedDocument pages. I looked into the decorator pattern but it seems i have to override all the concrete class properties in the decorator class for them to be visible. Is there a way of adding a wrapper that is derived from the concrete class that inherits the values of the base properties as follows:

```
    class BaseClass
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    class ConcreteClass : BaseClass
    {
        public int MyProperty { get; set; }
    }

    class ConcreteClassWrapper : ConcreteClass
    {
        public int AdditionalProperty { get; set; }

        public ConcreteClassWrapper(ConcreteClass cc) 
        {
            base = cc;
        }
    }

    private static void RunTime()
    {
        List<BaseClass> list = new List<BaseClass>();

        ConcreteClass cc = new ConcreteClass()
        {
            Name = "Original",
            MyProperty = 5
        };

        list.Add(cc);

        cc = new ConcreteClassWrapper(cc)
        {
            AdditionalProperty = 10
        };
    }
```

Obviously i cant just set 'base = cc'. Is there anyway to achieve this?

Comment: Maybe you can modify the binding so that it works with wrapper that does not inherit `ConcreteClass`, but instead contains it. How does the binding look like?

Comment: The binding is WPF so i just want to set the datacontext to the base class and if the properties are there is picks them up otherwise there are blank

Answer (score 0):

Can you modify `ConcreteClass` so that it has an additional constructor:

```
class ConcreteClass : BaseClass
{
    public int MyProperty { get; set; }

    public ConcreteClass(ConcreteClass copy)
    {
        this.MyProperty = copy.MyProperty;
    }
}

class ConcreteClassWrapper : ConcreteClass
{
    public int AdditionalProperty { get; set; }

    public ConcreteClassWrapper(ConcreteClass cc)
        base(cc)
    {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can imagine the wrapper class to be defined like this

```
class ConcreteClassWrapper : ConcreteClass
{
    public string Name { get; set; } // Inherited from BaseClass
    public int MyProperty { get; set; } // Inherited from ConcreteClass
    public int AdditionalProperty { get; set; } 
}
```

It contains all the members declared in the all the base classes, since it inherits them.

You can create a new instance like this (assuming that you have a default constructor)

```
var wrapper = new ConcreteClassWrapper { 
    Name = "xy", 
    MyProperty = 5, 
    AdditionalProperty = 7
};
```

However, if you want the wrapper to be a true wrapper, do not inherit from the base class

```
class ConcreteClassWrapper
{
    private ConcreteClass _cc;

    public ConcreteClassWrapper(ConcreteClass cc)
    {
        _cc = cc;
    }

    public string Name { get { return _cc.Name; } set { _cc.Name = value; } }
    public string MyProperty{ get { return _cc.MyProperty; } set { _cc.MyProperty = value; } }
    public int AdditionalProperty { get; set; } 
}
```

Comment: Thanks Olivier, I wanted to avoid this since my actual classess have 30-40 properties and i didn't want to have reflect them all in the new class

Comment: In my implementation of the "true" wrapper you are free to expose only the properties that you want.